# python re to find all combinations of capital and lower case letters of a given word

Tags: python, mysql, code-injection, python-re

Im attempting to create some code that would flag any attempts at mysql injection and im hoping that I can use Python re to find any combination of capital and lower case letters for MySQL keywords like 'or' and 'insert'

is there an re pattern that could find, for example, 'SElect' 'SELECT' 'seLECt' 'SELEcT' and any other combination of these words?

Comment: Try `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: It may be simpler to use the string `lower()` method to make all characters in the string  lower case. E.g. if `s = "SeLEct"` then `s.lower()` will be "select".

Comment: What is the reason in this task? MySQL object names are case-independent by default. And even when case sensitivity enabled it does not affect the injection possibility (i.e. the code cannot become or stop to be an injection by some letters case changing). So alter the code case to, for example, lower one, then analyze.